# Best way to handle large amounts of static text, images when creating pdf using iText

Tags: java, image, servlets, text, itext

We are going to use iText to create a large report. There will be a lot of static text and images that will be the same for every report. We will then insert dynamic data from a database into the report. The static data and the dynamic data will be mixed together when the report is finished. What is the best way to handle the static data. We are going to use a java servlet in a web application for the creation of the report. We want the report to be sent to the web page immediately, so performance is critical.

These are some of the ideas I had. Not sure if any of these are good ideas.

1.) Create a PDF with the static content then insert the dynamic data. If I go this way how would I know where to insert the dynamic data? Is it possible to bookmark place to insert data?

2.) Get the static data from a database. This seems like it would be difficult trying to design a database with static content that would have to consider things like pages, paragraphs, headings, images. I would also think that this would not be great for performance if the website gets hit hard.

3.) Cache the static content in the servlet context. This would seem to help performance but would still have the same design issues as the database.

I would love some opinions on the best way to store large amounts of static text when creatig a PDF using iText.

Thanks for your help
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the best way to do it, but this worked well for me in a similar situation,  I created a template file that I read into code, and in the template I had hash tagged variable holders that I used to find a location and replace with dynamic text from whatever source.  For example:

```
Hello #CUSTOMER_NAME#,  Thank you for the purchase of #RECENT_PURCHASES# on 
#RECEIPT_DATE#, for a total value of #RECEIPT_TOTAL#. ...
```

Like I said, it probably isn't ideal, but it really well for my needs.

Comment: I was hopping not to go this route. I did not want to hunt for special characters with in the PDF report. Not sure if this would be inefficient if the server got hit hard.

Comment: I agree, this is probably not a high performing solution.  The use this met was interfacing a system that required including an xml document that fed the security routines along with other files and information.  I had a template XML file, and I used the scenario described to make the security XML specific to whatever user and group was doing the uploading.